# How to get rank and max score where each user has many scores in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a Score table that hold user_id,score in MySql . each user has many scores .  I want to get best rank of each user ? 
I check a lot of solution but all of them work for table that each user has single score .

I tried this but sometimes user by min score got higher rank :

```
SET @rank= 0;;
SELECT Users.username, score, rank 
FROM ( 
  SELECT * , @rank := @rank +1 AS rank 
  FROM Scores 
  JOIN ( 
    SELECT userid AS user_id2, MAX( score ) AS max_score 
    FROM Scores 
    GROUP BY user_id2 
    ORDER BY max_score DESC 
  ) AS max_score_table ON max_score = Scores.score 
                      AND Scores.userid = user_id2 
) derived_table 
join Users On (Users.id=derived_table.user_id2) 
ORDER BY rank 
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question with sample data and desired results.  It is also nice to set up a SQL Fiddle and to show attempts that you have made to solve the problem.

Comment: Posting the code that doesn't work for your problem does help anyone understand your actual problem.  Edit your question and provide sample code and desired results.